# Changing the visibility of button value for logged in Wp user

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am using a 'Login' call to action `javascript` button. The button code has a value called `Login`. So the button is always displaying the `Login` text as a button name all time.

But I want, when any user logged in the site then this button name will be changed and all users will see the button name as `Log Out`. If someone click on the `Log Out` button then he will logged out.

**I want-**

- Logged out users/visitors will see the button name 'Login'
- Logged in users will see the button name 'Log Out' with log out action.

Can you please fix by editing my code?

**See my current code below:**

```
 <input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="Login" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();"><aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use session value with if statement to alternatively display your button

Comment: Show us your php code. When user logs in, you can set some session variable. When you render a page, check this variable, if it is set, render logout button, if not, render login button.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<a href="<?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?>logged.php<?php else:?>not_loggded.php<?php endif; ?>">
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()): ?> 
<?php _e('Logged); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php _e('Not logged); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you please show me the full code including your code here? I am confusing. I want to see the full code.

Comment: I am waiting for your reply. Can you please show the full code with my codes? Thanks

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Not' (T_STRING) in your code on line 6
<?php _e('Not logged); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type="button" style="background-color: red" value="<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { echo 'Logout'; } else { echo 'Login'; } ?>" data-reveal-id="tmpl_reg_login_container" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="tmpl_login_frm();"><aside id="sidebar-contact_page_sidebar" class="sidebar large-3 small-12 columns">
```

Comment: Hi, the code displaying blank. Nothing displaying. Can you please recheck your code? Please try to add all extensions carefully.

Comment: I checked your code at phpcodechecker.com and it showing some syntax error. Please test your code. And can you give me a full clean code?

Comment: try that again, I just edited in the missing semi colons.

Comment: sry, missed 2 semicolons :)